# How to add donation message in my joomla site without adding any custom code

Tags: joomla

I want to add Japan's Tsunami donation message for general public visiting my site. How can I do it without changing any code preferable in the top of my website?
My site: downloadformsindia dot com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can take what ever code the donation site you want to promote and put it in a Custom HTML module. Depending on your template, you might want to add a new, temporary position to index.php at the top of the page outside of the rest of the page structure. If your template already has a position that is well suited for the code you can also put it there so you don't have to modify the template code.